# Executing python script with selenium with batch (selenium error)

Tags: python, selenium, batch-file, pycharm

I'm trying to execute a python script with selenium module via batch file.
The python script itself runs perfectly OK, but when I try to execute the script through a .bat file it gives me the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium''

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Temp/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('http://www.example.com')
```

```
C:\Python\Python37\python.exe C:\PythonTest\testFile.py
```

The error printed is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ElGregory\PycharmProjects\PythonTest\testFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Which obviously is a Python error, but when the code is run in Pycharm it runs as expected. (=selenium installed correctly)

Any help apreciated.

Comment: If you're running it in PyCharm but not using `C:\Python\Python37\python.exe` it suggests that [tag:PyCarm] may be pointing to a different installation of [tag:Python] than where [tag:Selenium] is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because when you are running inside Pycharm, the libraries are installed in your virtual python environment (`venv`).

Either `activate` the virtual environment before running the python file for which you can read more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Or install your libraries globally

Comment: Based on your answer and comment from @Compo it was clear that It was just an idiotic mistake from my side.
Using \Python37\ instead of correct path \Python37-32\.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command, you most probably don't have `selenium` installed.

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).